# Error TypeError: catList.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I am a beginner in frontend development and now I am trying to display the data in this API
But I always get this error and the catList value is always empty and I don't know why

**Categories.jsx**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios'





const Categories = () => {
    const [catList,setCatList]=useState([])

    useEffect(()=>{
        const getCategory= async ()=>{
            const res =await axios.get('http://run.mocky.io/v3/a78af611-3af6-481c-98a0-ba04a5f7ce70')
            setCatList(res.data.problems[0].Diabetes[0].medications[0].medicationsClasses[0])
            console.log("catList",catList);
        }
        getCategory()
    },[])
    return (
        <div className='categories-section'>
            { catList.map((category,index)=>(
                <div className='category-item' key={index}>
                    <h1>{category}</h1>
                </div>
            ))} 
        </div>
    )
}

export default Categories
```

**App.js**

```
import './App.css';
import Categories from './components/Categories'
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Categories />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: What is the value of `res.data.problems[0].Diabetes[0].medications[0].medicationsClasses[0]`? (Console logging out `catList` won't give the the right answer here as setting state is asynchronous)

Comment: `res.data.problems[0].Diabetes[0].medications[0].medicationsClasses[0]` does not give you an array but an object

Comment: How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Use `res.data.problems[0].Diabetes[0].medications[0].medicationsClasses` instead for example

Comment: The problem is still there

Comment: How do I solve this problem? @DBS

Comment: @YassinMo Well the simplest way would be to actually check the API and see that the property you are setting the state with is not an array...

Comment: @YassinMo, Make sure res.data.problems[0].Diabetes[0].medications[0].medicationsClasses[0] returns an array, and also before you set api returned data directly to the component state make sure the data you received in correct shape, which is in this case an array of objects, Also you have your console.log in your component mount lifecycle method this is the reason why catList is always empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the `console.log("catList",catList);` outside useEffect.